# Multiple proxies each on different port with own basic authentication

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

i need to setup multiple proxies on different ports each haveing an own authentication username:password. Proxies are chained to another parent proxies. Actually squid provides that functionality, but i can't find the way to set different authentication for each port/proxy. 
So i'm searching for linux solution to achieve that functionality, Nginx or node.js script solution would be even better solution but i'm not sure if it's possible to configure them needed way.

Squid is okay to build proxy chains on multile ports though looks like i can't define own credentials for each port/proxy. So i'm searching for a quick solution to set up a proxy chained to a parent and authorised with basic mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone else will search for similar solution, the best one i got luck to find is proxy-tunnel library: https://github.com/apifytech/proxy-chain. it allows you to setup a proxy server quick and easy, you can define authentication and build chain with an upstream proxies, works same as squid but without configuration pains.